# Cocoapods Error v0.9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to use cocoapods to try and get a Firebase starter project running.
When running POD I get the following output :

POD v0.9.0

Usage: pod [command]

Commands:

```
create <app>            Create a new app
remote <app> <repo>     Create a app from a remote GitHub repo
rm <app>                Delete an app
start <app>             Start an app monitored by pm2
stop <app>              Stop an app
restart <app>           Restart an app that's already running
list                    List apps and status
startall                Start all apps not already running
stopall                 Stop all apps
restartall              Restart all running apps
prune                   Clean up dead files
hooks                   Update hooks after a pod upgrade
web [command]           Start/stop/restart the web interface
help                    You are reading it right now
```

There is no INIT command and when I try to initiate the POD it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have CocoaPods installed. Here's the output when I run `pod` by itself:

```
$ pod
Usage:

    $ pod COMMAND

      CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.

Commands:

    + cache          Manipulate the CocoaPods cache
    + debug          Start a debugging session
    + deintegrate    Deintegrate CocoaPods from your project
    + dependencies   Show project's dependency graph.
    + env            Display pod environment
    + gen            Generates Xcode workspaces from a podspec.
    + init           Generate a Podfile for the current directory
    + install        Install project dependencies according to versions from a
                     Podfile.lock
    + ipc            Inter-process communication
    + lib            Develop pods
    + list           List pods
    + outdated       Show outdated project dependencies
    + package        Package a podspec into a static library.
    + plugins        Show available CocoaPods plugins
    + repo           Manage spec-repositories
    + search         Search for pods
    + setup          Setup the CocoaPods environment
    + spec           Manage pod specs
    + trunk          Interact with the CocoaPods API (e.g. publishing new specs)
    + try            Try a Pod!
    + update         Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock

Options:

    --silent         Show nothing
    --version        Show the version of the tool
    --verbose        Show more debugging information
    --no-ansi        Show output without ANSI codes
    --help           Show help banner of specified command
```

Comment: Hi. Installed RVM , then installed Ruby using that and installed cocoapods again. Seems to give me the right output now when I execute POD

Answer (score 0):

Installed RVM
Installed Ruby 
ran : gem update --system
gem install rails --pre
running POD now gets 
Usage:

```
$ pod COMMAND

  CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.
```

Commands:

```
+ cache         Manipulate the CocoaPods cache
+ deintegrate   Deintegrate CocoaPods from your project
+ env           Display pod environment
+ init          Generate a Podfile for the current directory
+ install       Install project dependencies according to versions from a
                Podfile.lock
+ ipc           Inter-process communication
+ lib           Develop pods
+ list          List pods
+ outdated      Show outdated project dependencies
+ plugins       Show available CocoaPods plugins
+ repo          Manage spec-repositories
+ search        Search for pods
+ setup         Setup the CocoaPods environment
+ spec          Manage pod specs
+ trunk         Interact with the CocoaPods API (e.g. publishing new specs)
+ try           Try a Pod!
+ update        Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock
```

Options:

```
--silent        Show nothing
--version       Show the version of the tool
--verbose       Show more debugging information
--no-ansi       Show output without ANSI codes
--help          Show help banner of specified command
```